# Why can't I use "do" in "How many rooms have conditioner?"

Tags: word-choice, slang, word-order

I wonder why I can't use "do" in this question?

> How many rooms do have conditioner?

It means that all the rooms have conditioner, right?

But the question that I mentioned means some rooms don't have a conditioner.

I need an explanation why I couldn't use "do" in this question.

Comment: You can use "do".  It changes the emphasis of the question, to stress which rooms you want to count, and which you don't.

Comment: Try [ell.se], perhaps? More info [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Answer (score 5):

You can say the sentence with or without "do," but it will mean something different.

> How many rooms have conditioner?

is a simple question; you are asking which rooms do, and which rooms do not, have conditioner in them.

You would never ask:

> How many rooms *do* have conditioner?

unless it had already been established, earlier in the conversation, that some rooms did not have conditioner, and you want to establish a definite distinction between the set that do and the set that do not. For example: you could say:

> Joe, we have a problem--I just found out that housekeeping forgot to put conditioner in some of the rooms?
>
> Really? That's terrible! Well, how many rooms *do* have conditioner?

But you would not use "do" in a conversation like this one:

> Let's check the inventory of the rooms. They all have shampoo, and they all have conditioner.

Simply put, only use "do" in a construction like this if you're using it in opposition--express or implied--to "don't." A good rule of thumb is: if you couldn't use "do" on its own, don't use "do" with a noun. So you might say:

> This room doesn't have a television. How many rooms do?

or:

> This room doesn't have a television. How many rooms do have TV?

but you wouldn't walk into the room and ask:

> How many rooms do?

without the first part of the sentence--it wouldn't make sense. So you can't use "do have TV" on its own, either.

Also: I suspect you're also using "conditioner" wrong. "Conditioner" on its own is an uncountable noun, referring to a hair product that you use after shampooing.

> First I used the shampoo, which smelled fine. Then I used the conditioner, which made my hair smell like eels!

I suspect you meant to say "air conditioner," a machine used for cooling air inside a building. In English, "air conditioner" can be shortened to "A/C" or in some cases "air," but never to "conditioner."

"Air conditioner" is a countable noun, so in your sentence you would have to say:

> How many rooms have **an** air conditioner?

or, more idiomatically, you could use the uncountable version: "air conditioning":

> How many rooms have **air conditioning?**

Comment: Or, "How many rooms have air conditioners?"